# Are new users subjected to prejudicial or intensified scrutiny by reviewers?

Tags: discussion, review, moderators, new-users

I have an experience to share as a new contributor to unix.stackexchange.com where I sensed some slight undercurrents of prejudice.  It would be great to receive a response from the users mentioned here but any input, technical or otherwise, from others is welcome.  I was not able to respond in situ with my thoughts so pardon me for creating a new question.

**Observation 1: New contributors cannot comment on their own posts [Resolved]**
I attempted to contact a contributor via a minor edit to [muru's lowest rated answer to question 278443](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278463/439154) regarding the "mangled code", where he responded "you can always address editors to your post by commenting with @username".  I couldn't comment, only edit, my posts.  The resultant URL after clicking "comment" was: [What's the POSIX way to read an exact number of bytes from a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278443/whats-the-posix-way-to-read-an-exact-number-of-bytes-from-a-file/617134?noredirect=1#) where the query is `noredirect=1#`.

**Observation 2: A possibly valid edit by a new user is ignored**
Incidentally, I found a possible error in muru's answer to question 278443 where he said that the command `dd bs=1 count=1000000` "will be horrendously slow".  This involved processing only 1 million bytes which would not be slow.  A test on my dual-core took 1.8 seconds.

```
$dd if=/dev/urandom of=~/tmp1 ibs=1 count=1000000
1000000+0 records in
1953+1 records out
1000000 bytes transferred in 1.844224 secs (542233 bytes/sec)
```

With `bs=1` for large amounts such as 1TB then, yes, it would be much slower in comparison to `bs=64M`, which is probably what he had in mind.  Though I believe my reasoning was sound my edit request was rejected.

**Observation 3: Logical reasoning is not always required by high-rep users, only statements**
In my first draft of the edit to muru's answer I realised that I had altered it too much and decided to post [my own answer to question 278443](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/617134/439154).  I said "a partial read by `dd` with `ibs=1` would be unlikely".  A high-rep user [Stephen Kitt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/86440/stephen-kitt) commented that "it is impossible".  That comment has since been deleted but how is it impossible?  For raw data without a multiple of 8 bits i.e. 0< n mod 8 <8  and `ibs=1` where the block size is 1 byte or 8 bits how does `dd` deal with a read of, say, 3 bits?  I do not know, particularly with older media such as tape and older versions of `dd`.  My knowledge on `dd` is limited here.  If Stephen Kitt had the time to explain or point to a relevant post on this topic then this would fill in the gaps.  I have not yet found any further information to support his statement.

**Observation 4: Plausible solutions by new users are disparaged**
[Question 278443](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278443/whats-the-posix-way-to-read-an-exact-number-of-bytes-from-a-file/617134?noredirect=1#) is "What's the POSIX way to read an exact number of bytes from a file?".  I then added an option using the `read` command, stating that there are limitations after testing a few successful examples.  I received a comment recently from Stephen Kitt saying "POSIX read is very limited, so in the context of this question, your read approach doesn’t work".  "Limited" and "doesn't work" are mutually exclusive mathematical probabilities.  In the context of the question, `read` is a built-in command of POSIX that can be successfully used to read an exact number of bytes as long as certain conditions are met.  There are limitations, as stated in my answer, but the OP did not require a failsafe or limitless option.  Even so, if Stephen Kitt can briefly explain these limitations then I can understand why my answer doesn't work.

**Observation 5: Self-deletion of a post by a new user is not possible [Resolved]**
Seeing that my answer, described in Observation 4, was not beneficial I then attempted to delete it by clicking on the "delete" button at the bottom of the post: "share", "edit", "delete", "flag".  However, I was not able to do so.  The result is a client-side redirection to [What's the POSIX way to read an exact number of bytes from a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278443/whats-the-posix-way-to-read-an-exact-number-of-bytes-from-a-file/617134?noredirect=1#) where the query is `noredirect=1#`, which only goes to the top of the page.

**Observation 6: Prejudice favouring long-standing users**
I noted that muru's post on the same question (278443) possessed similar, if not, less merit than my answer, yet apparently received no critique from reviewers.  His post had a score of "-1" prior to my posted answer and "0" afterwards which indicates to me that it was probably upvoted by Stephen Kitt.

**Observation 7: High-rep users can edit and approve at will, even if incorrect**
A few days ago I posted an [answer to a Vim question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/616581/439154) at unix.stackexchange.com and a high-rep user [muru](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru) edited it in kind, but inadvertently introduced errors into the code.  It was a by-product of format conversion and I rectified it, but it appeared muru's edit wasn't reviewed by a third party because of certain privileges/status because the error was not noticed.

**Discussion**
As I have only spent a few days on the unix.stackexchange.com site it is too early to make conclusions.  I don't believe the aforementioned contributors are making any begrudging or personal attacks but I am of the impression that there is a hierarchical culture where there is bias between new and long-standing members.  I understand that moderators will need to politicise their responses, but is this true?  Is there a *pecking order* here or is this community on a level field of information sharing?

**My system (05-Nov-2020):**

- iMac 2006, Mac OS X 10.6.8.
- Chrome 49.0.2623.112 (64-bit) (unsupported).  Chrome settings: Javascript enabled, Images enabled, Cookies enabled.
- I can navigate to https://googleapis.github.io/ and http://sstatic.net/ pages.

Comment: There is no `-n` nor `-d` in POSIX `read` (because it's "limited"), so "doesn't work" was probably intended to be a polite way to say something about that suggestion.

Comment: You mention "moderators" in you message, but since none of the users that you mention are actual moderators on this site I assume that you mean this in the looser sense "contributor" or "editor". At the time of writing, [the site has four moderators](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators).

Comment: Regarding observation 3. If the user deleted their comment, why is this an issue?

Comment: Heh, if anything, I thought you might have upvoted my answer, since the most recent activity on my answer and on that question was by you. Also, to clarify, when I said "horrendously slow," I meant the operation in general, not just the specific read of a MB. It's like doing a `while read line; do echo "$line" | sed ...; done` instead of just `sed ...`.

Comment: No, you're wrong. It's me who upvoted muru's answer, not Stephen Kitt. I upvoted it not because I found it great, but because I found it no shittier than the highly upvoted answer by Gilles, which I had downvoted (because it made incorrect claims, like that `cat` ever choked on NUL bytes or inputs not terminated by newlines). I was unaware of all the drama around that Q&A -- I got there by just idly clicking around.

Comment: The "add a comment" link is not a real link; it dynamically creates a comment form on the page when clicked, and going to the URL as you have takes you nowhere, suggesting that JavaScript is not working for you. The deletion button is the same.

Comment: Firstly I appreciate all the responses here which have been professional and courteous; I thank everyone for the education and apologise for the use of time over a trivial matter.  Many of my statements were flawed and blinded and I accept responsibility for this.  Please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: Michael Homer, thank you for identifying my problem with the buttons.  It was a client-side Javascript issue.  Because I was able to edit posts I did not suspect it to be the cause of the problems.   The Javascript on my browser showed limitations with other websites.  It was not until I tested the the buttons on a new system that I confirmed the problem.

Comment: Michael Homer, again, you are correct that I was not testing with POSIX `read` on my machine.  My mistake.

Comment: terdon, thank you for the thorough answer and the  POSIX `read` specification.  Now I see where I went wrong.  In future I will pay greater heed to my test environment.  The phrase "was probably upvoted by Stephen Kitt" was not quite an assumption but a calculated guess.  There was only one vote that day and it seemed to coincide with Stephen Kitt's comment.  But yes, it should not have been made.

Comment: My apologies to muru and Stephen Kitt for some of the ignorant and subjective statements.  There was no technical or ethical fault on your part.

Comment: terdon, yes, I was logged in when attempting to perform the delete and comments, as my login symbol was visible in the top right of the header.  If new users are permitted to comment, delete, upvote, downvote etc on their own zero-rated posts, then my case was isolated.

Comment: - Stephen Kitt, yes, I was not using POSIX `read`.  Though I cannot see the first-posts nor the late-answers queues because I "need at least 500 reputation", I can see how you found my answer.  I did read the question, answers and even the links in the question.  I admit that my answer had no added benefit.  My purpose for navigating to that question was initially to contact muru by editing his answer.  Things became entangled when I created my own answer which was basically a duplicate of the other answers.  When I couldn't delete that answer I attempted vainly to improve it.

Comment: Kusalananda, I incorrectly assumed Stephen Kitt was a moderator because he found out very quickly that I edited my post.  For such a heavily used site I expected around 20 - 50 moderators.  I think his comment was later deleted not because it contained false information but because it became irrelevant.  But I still wanted it explained.

Comment: Thank you for your honesty and humour user414777.  As for your comment that Gilles 'SO- stop being evil' "made incorrect claims, like that `cat` ever choked on NUL bytes or inputs not terminated by newlines", he did say "some older implementations [of text processing tools]" but doesn't explicitly state which.

Comment: In summary, here were my incorrect assertions: (a) muru and Stephen Kitt were moderators; (b) not being able to upvote, downvote, comment on or delete self-posts were designed features aimed to limit new users; (c) the in-built command `read` on my Mac OS X was POSIX.

Comment: I'm glad, really @rwarvi because I was in a slightly similar situation as you were when I first joined Unix, as well as some other minor times when it happened. I also notice a lot of what you noticed, ***especially*** Observation 3, which I never really knew how to complain about, because of many obvious reasons. So yes, I'm really glad someone else noticed this and proved to me that this wasn't just a figment of my imagination. Thank you P.S.: Before it is pointed, yes, I already read the answers to this post.

Comment: @rwarvi muru is still not a moderator.

Answer (score 15):

First of all, thank you for coming here to Meta with a polite, calm question as you have done. I know how confusing the rules can be to new users, and it is always appreciated when people ask instead of ranting.

Next, I want to point out that none of the users you mention are moderators. Moderators are elected by the community and have a `♦` after their names. You can see the list of moderators here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators

The people you mention are high-rep users. This means they have enough reputation to be able to perform certain actions on the site. For more on the various reputation thresholds, please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges.

On to your observations!

**Observation 1: New contributors cannot comment on their own posts**

New users can comment on their posts. They can't comment on other people's posts (you need 50 rep for that, which is essential to block spammers from commenting). If you really couldn't comment on your post, then that's a bug. Could you please try again and confirm it so we can report it?

**Observation 2: A possibly valid edit by a new user is ignored**

Your edit can be seen here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/356718. You are removing the "horrendously slow" but you don't actually give any arguments to support it. Also, the message you used to explain the edit was your attempt to contact Muru. So Muru probably thought the whole edit was only to contact him (you need a minimum number of changes to suggest an edit, so he may have thought you just removed the phrase only to get the edit through). If you really feel that "horrendously slow" is worth editing out, you can try submitting a new edit but this time give your reasons for removing it so that the post's author can understand.

**Observation 3: Logical reasoning is not required by moderators, only statements**

I don't really understand the problem here. First, as I said in the beginning, the user who commented is not a moderator. Second, if a comment has been deleted, why are we still discussing it? Perhaps the author of the comment made a mistake, realized it and then deleted it. In any case, comments are free, you can say what you want in them (you shouldn't, ideally you should only comment about the question, but you're free to write what you like).

In any case, I can see [a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278443/whats-the-posix-way-to-read-an-exact-number-of-bytes-from-a-file/617134#comment1155462_617134) there now:

> POSIX read is very limited, so in the context of this question, your read approach doesn’t work :-/. – Stephen Kitt

The comment is explaining that the [POSIX implementation of `read`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html) is limited. Specifically, I assume Stephen meant that POSIX `read` doesn't support `-d` or `-n`, but only `-r`. This means that your answer won't work with POSIX `read`. Yes, Stephen could have made that a little bit clearer, but next time just answer the comment and ask for clarifications (always assuming there's no bug that stops you from commenting on your own posts).

In all, I just don't see any problem here nor any reason to think this has something to do with your being a new user. I've been a user for several years now, I'm in the top 10 users by reputation and an elected mod and I still get comments pointing out errors in my answers. This is a good thing!

**Observation 4: Plausible solutions by new users are disparaged**

This seems to be the same as the point above. As explained, your answer doesn't work for POSIX read since it doesn't support the `-n` or `-d` options, and the question was asking specifically about POSIX read. Therefore, your answer doesn't work for the question. Again, this has nothing to do with your being a new user. Also, the only thing that happened is that a helpful user explained what the problem was. I don't understand what made you feel your answer was "disparaged". There's no disparagement here, only a polite comment pointing out a problem.

**Observation 5: Self-deletion of a post by a new user is not possible**

You can delete your own answer unless it has been accepted. Just click on the "delete" button under the post:

[image: delete button]

Again, if you couldn't, there's a bug so please try again and let us know. Make sure you are using the same account to log in. Could you perhaps have tried to delete it when not logged in?

**Observation 6: Prejudice to moderators and long-standing users**

Once again, no mods were involved. And Muru's post doesn't use `read -n` so it doesn't have the issue that Stephen helpfully pointed out about your answer. Why, then, should that answer have the same critique? As for who voted, you have no way of knowing that (not even moderators have access to voting data), so I would urge you not to make assumptions.

But no matter who voted, people are free to vote as they like. Nobody has voted on  your post (although I would understand it if they had downvoted since one of the solutions you offer doesn't work with POSIX `read`). Two people have voted on Muru's answer, one person found it good and upvoted and one found it bad and downvoted. So if anything, it is Muru,  an established, high-rep user who is facing "prejudice" since it is he who got a downvote. Now I don't think that's prejudice at all, I am just pointing out that he's the only one who got a downvote, not you.

Finally, the SE sites try to be egalitarian. However, because there is the rep system, it is indeed true that sometimes people with more rep are listened to more. This isn't encouraged, and shouldn't be the case, but we're all humans so some people do react differently to high rep users. I'm afraid nobody can do anything about that though since it is down to how each individual reacts. Reputation on this site is supposed to represent the level of trust the community places in a user. Therefore, the more rep you have, the more trusted you are and the more trusted you are the more weight your statements may have for some people. This is just human nature though and is not under any circumstances the official stance of the community or the moderator team.

In theory, every user is supposed to be treated equally. In practice, this sometimes does fail but when it does, if you feel someone is being rude or dismissive of you because you're new, please flag the rudeness or come here and open a discussion on Meta. No system is perfect, and having reputation can indeed breed a feeling of elitism, but we do try and avoid that.

Comment: I am able to comment, upvote, downvote, delete my posts etc using a more recent system: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.418], Chrome Version 86.0.4240.183 (Official Build) (32-bit).  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 8):

terdon has already addressed most of your points, but your question includes some issues that I think only I can address.

First, I’m not a moderator, and even though I have a lot of fake Internet points, I don’t have all that many special powers as a result.

Second, it is quite possible that new users are subjected to more scrutiny than others, because their posts show up for review in [the first posts review queue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts) or in [the late answers review queue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers); you can see my review from the latter [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/356719). I actually hadn’t realised until just now that the late answers queue only includes new users’ answers! My review wasn’t related to your being new; it was related to your answer being a late answer. I expect these to add relevant information which isn’t present in existing answers; I commented as such on your answer, since the `ibs=1` approach had already been described elsewhere, but I didn’t take further action (*e.g.* suggesting that your answer should be deleted).

**Observation 3**

I tend to assume that people interested in a question have read all the surrounding material (in the question, comments, answers, and linked questions), which is perhaps unfair. The impossibility of partial reads when the input block size is 1, as far as `dd` is concerned at least, is explained [in this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278465/86440):

> This suggests a solution: **use an input block size of 1**. No matter how the input is produced, there's no way for `dd` to read a partial block if the input block size is 1. (This is not completely obvious: `dd` could read a block of size 0 if it's interrupted by a signal — but if it's interrupted by a signal, the `read` system call returns -1. A `read` returning 0 is only possible if the file is opened in non-blocking mode, and in that case a `read` had better not be considered to have been performed at all. In blocking mode, `read` only returns 0 at the end of the file.)

**Observation 4**

When I wrote “POSIX `read` is very limited”, I was only saying that: [`read`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html), as defined by POSIX, doesn’t have much in the way of options, and is pretty much limited to handling newline-delimited input as full lines. As a result of that, “in the context of your question, your `read` approach doesn’t work”. The two statements don’t qualify the same thing: the first qualifies POSIX `read`, the second qualifies your use of `read`. Because the question specifies POSIX only, you can’t use extensions to `read` as implemented in Bash for example.

> In the context of the question, `read` is a built-in command of POSIX that can be successfully used to read an exact number of bytes as long as certain conditions are met.

As far as POSIX is concerned, `read` is a utility (traditionally a shell built-in, but the specification doesn’t require that), and as defined by POSIX it can’t be used to read an exact number of bytes.

**Observation 6**

I don’t know who upvoted [muru’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278463/86440), but it wasn’t me. If there’s one thing to always bear in mind regarding votes, it’s that you can never assume anything about them.

Here’s proof:

[image: Screenshot of muru’s answer with votes expanded]

Neither of the arrows are highlighted, which means I haven’t voted either way.

Comment: [It was me](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5669/are-new-users-subjected-to-prejudicial-or-intensified-scrutiny-by-moderators#comment11172_5669) who upvoted muru's answer and downvoted Gilles' answer. Now everybody should know where to direct their comtempt and derision.

Comment: @user414777 at themselves, I should hope, if they reckon votes on Unix.SE should result in directing contempt and derision anywhere...